# Accessing logged in user in Symfony2 from php template

Tags: php, symfony

My question is how can I access the logged in user from the view? I know it's possible with twigs `{app.user}`, but I have to do it in php template. Is it possible to get the user from php template? Something like `$app->getUser()` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the user through the `security.context` service. For example, you could write in your controller:

```
$User = null;
$securityToken = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

if (is_object($securityToken) && is_callable([$securityToken, 'getUser']))
    $User = $securityToken->getUser();
```

Note: It is possible that the `$User` variable does not really contain your user entity. In this case, you should additionally check that `$User` is an instance of your user entity:

```
… && is_object($User) && is_callable([$User, 'getId']) && $User->getId() …
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the user to log in using Twig templates magic method {{ app.user.username }}

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I use php templating. Whatever, It turned out, I can access the service container from the view too, so I can call for the `$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` methods, that returns the user.